# Does ARC eliminate the need for temporary variables?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Without ARC-enabled, we write

```
NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  @"a",
                  @"b",
                  @"c",
                  @"d",
                  nil];

self.allItems = items;
[items release];
```

I just wonder whether we can take a shortcut with ARC-enabled like this:

```
self.allItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  @"a",
                  @"b",
                  @"c",
                  @"d",
                  nil];
```

Can we eliminate `items` when we use ARC? What's the best practice?

Comment: I would change tthe title to "Does ARC eliminate _the need for_ temporary variables?". Right now, it sounds like ARC is doing some sort of compiler optimization behind your back, which is not what you meant to ask.

Comment: Thanks ranReloaded. I modified the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can eliminate the `items` variable if you're using ARC.  I suggest you eliminate it if you don't need it elsewhere and you don't think it makes your code easier to understand.  I would definitely eliminate it in your example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the second example you showed is just fine under ARC, and is probably desirable because it's more concise.

Answer (score 1):

The second example will work and is the best practice now. With ARC you no longer need to call retain or release.